# How can I replace a image with the same tag on my private remote registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

When I build and push to my private registry it works the first time. But when I change some code and do it once more I get several `46a1f4142b6a: Layer already exists`.

I build and push with the commands to my remote (in my network) registry:

`docker build -t 192.168.1.5:5000/myapp:latest -f myapp.Dockerfile .`

`docker push 192.168.1.5:5000/myapp:latest`

I was expecting the image with the tag `latest` to be replaced.

Comment: That sounds perfectly good and normal. Docker only pushes the layers that have changes to them. E.g. there's no need to push the base image you've based your image on again, since that layer is already in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

A container image is made up of multiple layers, where each layer represents a change or addition to the previous layer. These layers are built on top of each other, and the final image is a combination of all the layers. Each layer is a read-only file system that contains the changes made to the previous layer. This layered approach allows for efficient storage, distribution, and management of container images.

When you build a container image with a Dockerfile, each instruction in the Dockerfile creates a new layer in the image. For example, if you have a Dockerfile with the following instructions:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
```

The first instruction will create a layer that is based on the ubuntu:20.04 image, the second instruction will create a new layer with the updates of the package manager and the third instruction will create a new layer that has the nginx package installed.

It's also important to note that when you change something in an image, it doesn't change the existing layer but creates a new one on top of the previous one, that's why the size of the image doesn't decrease when you remove something from it, but instead, it increases the size of the image.

So when you build and push an image to a private container registry, the first time it the image and tag you are pushing do not already exist in the registry. The "docker build" command creates a new image with the specified tag, and the "docker push" command uploads that image to the registry.

However, when you make changes to the code and try to build and push the image again using the same tag, the "docker push" command will return the error message "Layer already exists" because the image with that tag already exists in the registry. The push command is only uploading the changed layers so hence for the other layers there is the message: "Layer already exists".